# After establishing the TCP connection, the server sends an RST message to the client, why?

Tags: tcp, wireshark

1.

[image]

2.

[image]

Is Timeout re transmission ?

Comment: How should we know? You've got the two applications, you know what they're trying to do. From the log it seems that you either have serious network issues, or you're dealing with an attack of some kind - RST just means "I'm totally confused, let's try all over again".

Comment: If you look carefully, then you'll notice that there has been several issues with the connection which include.
1. TCP duplicate ACK
2. TCP out of order
3. TCP retransmission
These might lead to something which shows that the connection has some issues.

Comment: I'm turning to <Unix NetWork Programming Volume 1> for help

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you might need to take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5272026/tcp-server-sends-rst-ack-immediately-after-receiving-syn-from-client?rq=1) answer. The answer suspects that the port might not be correct or a firewall issue.

Comment: There is nothing in the link about the port not being correct.

Comment: Hi @EJP. 
It says "...means the port is closed". So, it does mention about the port.

Comment: client can send the data to server at frist, The network latency might be one of the reasons, when I send the data to the port, the port is already closed, so I receive RST.